# Convert Datetime values in Varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have dates stored in a `varchar` column, I know date values should be stored in a `datetime` column but it is not my database to change.

When I try and convert the `datetime` values into another format the output always comes out as `1900-01-01` even though it's stored in the database like `13/04/2012`, I want it to be like `2012-04-13`.

My code at the moment is like this:-

```
(SELECT ISDATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), myDate, 120)) FROM myTable
```

Any ideas as to my it is always outputting `1900-01-01`, this is in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You should convert it to `datetime` like `CONVERT(datetime, myDate, 120)` since you said your dates stored in a `varchar` field

Comment: I would highly recommend you change your column to a datetime instead of varchar. Storing data in the wrong datatype is nothing but hassles for the life of the system.

Comment: @Rahul when I try that it is saying The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @SeanLange I would like to change it but it is not possible as the column contains other data as well as dates, and is part of a large system with millions of records unfortunately I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Try british SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, myDate, 103) Here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, myDate, 103), 120) FROM myTable
```